# manipulating .txt file data in pyspark and changing the datatype

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, data-structures, pyspark

Im new to the field of IT. I am trying to perform simple functions on spark shell (pyspark) using python. The file is in `.txt` format and has only numbers in it. I uploaded it with the line

```
numbers_rdd = sc.textFile("/users/hadoop/numbers.txt")
```

I tried to get the mean using

```
numbers_rdd.mean()
```

however, [the output was this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tasJw.png)

i believe it is because i would need to convert the data in the textfile from string to numbers but im not sure. Please advise on how to proceed.

numbers_rdd.take(5) [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jDbm.png)

Comment: Can you show the result of numbers_rdd.take(5)

Comment: i uploaded it in the original post

Answer (score 0):

You are loading numbers from a text file where each row of numbers is in a different rdd element, so:

Split each row, cast to int and flatten the resulting list so you will have each number as a separate element:

```
numbers_rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [int(y) for y in x.split()]).mean()
```

Comment: it works! I was going to try this numbers_rdd.map(lambda x: x.split('\t')).\
    map(lambda y: (int(y[0]), float(y[2]), int(y[1]))) however it seems i was unable to get to the int(y[9]) due to some issues with my virtualbox. Would it have worked that way?

Comment: If you know the exact amount of elements after the split you can convert them individually, yes. BUT you have to flatMap the result otherwise you will have a tuple of numbers from each line in the file and not separate numbers.